# c# Paypal smart button server side integration - await.......continually waiting

Tags: c#, asp.net, paypal, webforms

I'm in the the process of implementing the server side version of the paypal smart buttons.

Currently using a sandbox account for this purpose.

Following https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/reference/server-integration/setup-sdk/

The create order JS triggers my server side code. The following lines seems to be ok on the server side process (referenced https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/reference/server-integration/set-up-transaction/):

```
OrdersCreateRequest request = new OrdersCreateRequest();
request.Prefer("return=representation");
request.RequestBody(BuildRequestBody());
//3. Call PayPal to set up a transaction
```

However on the next line, the client side login page starts to load/pops up)......but nothing happens and the lines after the line below don't seem to run.

```
var response = await PayPalClient.client().Execute(request); // This seems to hang, but putting try catch doesn't seem to run anything either.
```

The request variable value also seems to look a bit odd too:

```
{Method: POST, RequestUri: '<null>', Version: 1.1, Content: <null>, Headers:
{
  Prefer: return=representation
}}
```

I'm thinking I should be expecting the RequestUri to be sandbox.paypal.com, so perhaps this might be the cause.

Has anyone else has this problem or could advise where I might be going wrong? I know when I did the old PPE implementation the documentation was wrong on PayPals site, so I'm thinking perhaps this is a similar situation, but I can't figure it out.

TIA
Stu

Comment: there is no reason to add an extra thread when you call Execute in asp.net because already you are in a new thread with the call. You may put a new thread in a desktop application to not hand the user interface but no reason to do that on web call. Try to make direct call to see if works

Comment: Thx Aristos, however. I still couldn't get this to work. Removing the threading initially looked like it was working, but then in the response it stated "awaitingauthorisation" which when I looked into it, it seemed to be related to the fact it needs to be in the thread for the call...but then, it just hangs.

Comment: I believe I found an answer to this.
Fire the request to an ashx file and ensure you implement HttpTaskAsyncHandler on the handler class. This will allow the line 
    var response = await PayPalClient.client().Execute(request);
to run and not get stuck